# Google maps api not visible in website but works in jsFIddle

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am wondering why I do not get an error when viewing my code in a Fiddle but am unable to view the map when copied into my website. The only error I see in the console refers the 'function CreateMarker(obj) line of my js code. I am new to js so I am not sure what the issue is.

Console: "Exception in onResRdy: TypeError: Cannot read property 'htmlRes' of undefined"

Any help with figuring out why the map doesnt display would be greatly appreciated and any insight into the difference between jsFiddle and my PROD view would be a bonus.Here is the code example[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cparsnow/dL611x8b/2/) and here is my  [website](http://hopshedd.com/)

```js
var geocoder;
var map;
var markers = Array();
var infos = Array();

function initialize() {
    // prepare Geocoder
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    // set initial position (New York)
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.7143528,-74.0059731);

    var myOptions = { // default map options
        zoom: 12,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap_canvas'), myOptions);
}

// clear overlays function
function clearOverlays() {
    if (markers) {
        for (i in markers) {
            markers[i].setMap(null);
        }
        markers = [];
        infos = [];
    }
}

// clear infos function
function clearInfos() {
    if (infos) {
        for (i in infos) {
            if (infos[i].getMap()) {
                infos[i].close();
            }
        }
    }
}

// find address function
function findAddress() {
    var address = document.getElementById("gmap_where").value;

    // script uses our 'geocoder' in order to find location by address name
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) { // and, if everything is ok

            // we will center map
            var addrLocation = results[0].geometry.location;
            map.setCenter(addrLocation);

            // store current coordinates into hidden variables
            document.getElementById('lat').value = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            document.getElementById('lng').value = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

            // and then - add new custom marker
            var addrMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: addrLocation,
                map: map,
                title: results[0].formatted_address,
                icon: 'marker.png'
            });
        } else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
        }
    });
}

// find custom places function
function findPlaces() {

    // prepare variables (filter)
    var type = document.getElementById('gmap_type').value;
    var radius = document.getElementById('gmap_radius').value;
    var keyword = document.getElementById('gmap_keyword').value;

    var lat = document.getElementById('lat').value;
    var lng = document.getElementById('lng').value;
    var cur_location = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

    // prepare request to Places
    var request = {
        location: cur_location,
        radius: radius,
        types: [type]
    };
    if (keyword) {
        request.keyword = [keyword];
    }

    // send request
    service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    service.search(request, createMarkers);
}

// create markers (from 'findPlaces' function)
function createMarkers(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {

        // if we have found something - clear map (overlays)
        clearOverlays();

        // and create new markers by search result
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            createMarker(results[i]);
        }
    } else if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
        alert('Sorry, nothing is found');
    }
}

// creare single marker function
function createMarker(obj) {

    // prepare new Marker object
    var mark = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: obj.geometry.location,
        map: map,
        title: obj.name
    });
    markers.push(mark);

    // prepare info window
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: '<img src="' + obj.icon + '" /><font style="color:#000;">' + obj.name + 
        '<br />Rating: ' + obj.rating + '<br />Vicinity: ' + obj.vicinity + '</font>'
    });

    // add event handler to current marker
    google.maps.event.addListener(mark, 'click', function() {
        clearInfos();
        infowindow.open(map,mark);
    });
    infos.push(infowindow);
}

// initialization
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
#gmap_canvas {
    height: 700px;
    position: relative;
    width: 900px;
}
.actions {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    bottom: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 30px;
    z-index: 2;

    border-top: 1px solid #abbbcc;
    border-left: 1px solid #a7b6c7;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #a1afbf;
    border-right: 1px solid #a7b6c7;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
}
.actions label {
    display: block;
    margin: 2px 0 5px 10px;
    text-align: left;
}
.actions input, .actions select {
    width: 85%;
}
.button {
    background-color: #d7e5f5;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #d7e5f5), color-stop(100%, #cbe0f5));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #d7e5f5, #cbe0f5);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #d7e5f5, #cbe0f5);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #d7e5f5, #cbe0f5);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #d7e5f5, #cbe0f5);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #d7e5f5, #cbe0f5);
    border-top: 1px solid #abbbcc;
    border-left: 1px solid #a7b6c7;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #a1afbf;
    border-right: 1px solid #a7b6c7;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 white;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 white;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 white;
    color: #1a3e66;
    font: normal 11px "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    line-height: 1;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: 6px 0 7px 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #fff;
    width: 150px;
}
.button:hover {
    background-color: #ccd9e8;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #ccd9e8), color-stop(100%, #c1d4e8));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ccd9e8, #c1d4e8);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ccd9e8, #c1d4e8);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ccd9e8, #c1d4e8);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ccd9e8, #c1d4e8);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #ccd9e8, #c1d4e8);
    border-top: 1px solid #a1afbf;
    border-left: 1px solid #9caaba;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #96a3b3;
    border-right: 1px solid #9caaba;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 #f2f2f2;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 #f2f2f2;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 #f2f2f2;
    color: #163659;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.button:active {
    border: 1px solid #8c98a7;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px 2px #abbccf, 0 0 1px 0 #eeeeee;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px 2px #abbccf, 0 0 1px 0 #eeeeee;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px 2px #abbccf, 0 0 1px 0 #eeeeee;
}
```

```html
<div id="gmap_canvas"></div>
<div class="actions">
    <div class="button">
        <label for="gmap_where">Where:</label>
        <input id="gmap_where" type="text" name="gmap_where" /></div>
    <div id="button2" class="button" onclick="findAddress(); return false;">Search for address</div>
    <div class="button">
        <label for="gmap_keyword">Keyword (optional):</label>
        <input id="gmap_keyword" type="text" name="gmap_keyword" /></div>
    <div class="button">
        <label for="gmap_type">Type:</label>
        <select id="gmap_type">
            <option value="art_gallery">art_gallery</option>
            <option value="atm">atm</option>
            <option value="bank">bank</option>
            <option value="bar">bar</option>
            <option value="cafe">cafe</option>
            <option value="food">food</option>
            <option value="hospital">hospital</option>
            <option value="police">police</option>
            <option value="store">store</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
        <label for="gmap_radius">Radius:</label>
        <select id="gmap_radius">
            <option value="500">500</option>
            <option value="1000">1000</option>
            <option value="1500">1500</option>
            <option value="5000">5000</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="lat" name="lat" value="40.7143528" />
    <input type="hidden" id="lng" name="lng" value="-74.0059731" />
    <div id="button1" class="button" onclick="findPlaces(); return false;">Search for objects</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your   website  your  "map_canvas"  div   don't have fixed div (using postion: relative then height and width is trasformed both in 100% and so you don't see nothing ) or all the parent of the map_canva div don't have a proper height setted
then  set a proper height for  all the parent container

```
 html, body, #gmap_canvas { 
     width: 100%; 
     height: 100%; 
     margin: 0; 
     padding: 0; }

  #gmap_canvas { 
     position: relative;
   }
```

or set  fixed value this way

```
#gmap_canvas {
    height: 700px;

    width: 900px;
 }
```

Comment: I also found that I can modify the CSS parent containers.                         <code>    html, body, #gmap_canvas {
                             width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
                             margin: 0;
                             padding: 0;
                     }
 #gmap_canvas {
                     position: relative;
 }</code>

Comment: you got it, thank you so much. Now I can transform to the screen width and height